# Mobile android app that can import a Metamask private key?

Tags: wallets, metamask, android

I'm having some issues sending out from metamask and getting failed transactions. I think maybe I should use another app on android if possible. What android wallet apps can import a Metamask private key?

Answer (score 1):

You just need the `mnemonics` provided by the metamask when creating new wallet. Use any wallet that supports `mnemonics` and it will have(import) all the private and public keys.